# How many ways can you express an integer as the sum of positive integers and each sum does not include any 2s?

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, integer-partitions

I came up across this question while self-studying combinatorics. I am supposed to derive a recurrence relation, however I am not sure how to approach or even start this problem. The order matters.

Comment: Does order matter?  If we want to express $4$, do $1+1+1+1,1+3, 3+1, 4$ all count for four ways?

Comment: Then you are looking for [strong compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) that do not include $2$.  You can get an expression by summing over the options of the last term.  It is not what we usually call a recurrence because it doesn't have a fixed number of terms.

Comment: What was the source of your question, @mosalah.  Please cite the source of your question. Can you define what a recurrence relation is.  It sounds like you really haven't read earlier lessons before asking this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ross Millikan said in the comments, you're asking about integer compositions.  If the order does not matter, the term is integer partitions.

The number of such compositions of $n$ that include no 2 is given by the recurrence
$$a(n) = a(n-1) + a(n-2) + a(n-4)$$
for $n \ge 4$ with initial values $a(0) = a(1) = a(2) = 1$ and $a(3) = 2$, which is [A005251](https://oeis.org/A005251) in the On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences.

The recurrence can be understood combinatorially: To build the desired compositions of $n$ from the previous sets,

(a) put $+1$ at the end of these compositions of $n-1$,

(b) make the last part of these compositions of $n-2$ longer by a length of 2 (e.g., $1+3 \mapsto 1+5$), and

(c) put $+4$ at the end of these compositions of $n-4$.

Step (a) produces all of these compositions of $n$ that end with $+1$, step (b) makes the ones that end $+3$, $+5$, $+6$, etc., (not $+4$ since these compositions don't have any 2s), and (c) produces that ones that end with $+4$.  There are a few routine details you might want to work out to show this describes a bijection.

Comment: This applies to you as well; please read thoroughly, the meta post [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?cb=1)

Comment: @amWhy I've read the meta post you referenced.  Can you help me understand the issue here?  I don't see that the question is a duplicate.  Certainly it would be better to have the statement in the body rather than the title, so would editing the question help?  It seems to be a valid mathematical query.

Comment: The qustion post is rather far away from what is a "Good Question" (see link in the post linked to).

Answer (score -1):

Divide the ways to express a number $n$ into those that end in $1$ and those that do not.  To express $n+1$ you can take an expression of $n$ and add $+1$ to it.  If an expression does not end in $+1$ you can increase the last addend by $1$.  If the expression ends in $+1$ you can change it to $+3$.  You get a pair of coupled recurrences.  Starting from $4=3+1$ you can go to $5=3+1+1$ or $6=3+3$.  From $4=1+3$ you get $5=1+4$ and $5=1+3+1$.  You should be able to convince yourself that every expression can be built up uniquely this way.